# PHP file_get_contents function

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents

I am developing php-based websites. When I try to load a file from the same directory using file_get_contents, the server did return some string, but php code of that file are also returned. I want the file after compiled by php, not the native code. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: getting file contents from url may be? I mean like `file_get_contents("www.yoursite.com/page1.php")`

Comment: Are you looking for an opcode version of the PHP file, or the output produced if it's run?

Comment: **RTFM!** http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
include "file.php";
```

Comment: why include? he wants the output of the file not the phpscript itself

Comment: See, thats what he wanted. @Akam

Answer (score 0):

call the file_get_contents on the url and not on the path

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the include() function instead.

Answer (score 0):

When wanting use the contents of a PHP file for example to create a pdf, and you want the parsed output, not the code, one can trap the output buffer of the include operation.

```
ob_start();
include 'something.php';
$html = ob_get_clean();
ob_end_clean();
$this->mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```